# Spring-boot-hibernate5 + yml properties + xml properties

Tags: java, xml, spring, yaml, spring-data-jpa

I don't know how to use a multiple datasource created in yml with profiles and use generated datasources into xml context properties.
Anyone can help-me?

---

application.yml

```
   spring:
   profiles.active: development
---

    spring:
        profiles: development
    datasource:
        db-db2:
          url: jdbc:db2://db2url:50000/database
          username: username
          password: pwd
          driver-class-name: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
          test-on-borrow: true
          validation-query: VALUES current date
        db-oracle:
          url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@db_contract_dev
          username: username
          password: pwd
          driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
          test-on-borrow: true
          validation-query: SELECT 1 FROM dual
```

---

application.xml

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">       
        <property name="dataSource" ref="db-db2"/> 
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PU" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="JpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.inc.dao.repository" 
   entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
   transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
```

I try to use datasource into entitymanager factory like
**`<property name="dataSource" ref="db-db2"/>`**

Comment: I've see an solution but not with xml. [example with class config](http://smasue.github.io/spring-yml-datasources)